# getting a type for the values of a string enum

Tags: typescript

I have a string enumeration that looks like:

```
export enum FMEvents {
  RECORD_ADDED = "@firemodel/RECORD_ADDED",
  RECORD_CHANGED = "@firemodel/RECORD_CHANGED",
  RECORD_MOVED = "@firemodel/RECORD_MOVED",
  RECORD_REMOVED = "@firemodel/RECORD_REMOVED",
}
```

I'd like to be able to be able to constrain input into a function to the string values of enumeration (e.g., "@firemodel/RECORD_ADDED", etc.).

I thought I could maybe just do the following for the method signture:

```
public doSomething(event: keyof FMEvents) { ... }
```

but the typing for that is all wrong (I think it's giving me the keys of the enum object, not sure but definitely wrong).

I then tried just:

```
public doSomething(event: FMEvents) { ... }
```

This allows me to call `doSomething()` with `FMEvents.RECORD_CHANGED` but it does not allow me to call it with the resolved key of `doSomething("@firemodel/RECORD_CHANGED")`.

What I'm looking for is a way to constraint it to the string defined as values in the Enum and nothing else. With this I'm hoping both calling methods above will pass the type checking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TypeScript 4.1 introduced [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) which, among other things, will convert enums to their string representations.  So your goal can be accomplished simply as:

```
function doSomething(event: `${FMEvents}`) { }

doSomething("@firemodel/RECORD_CHANGED"); // okay
doSomething(FMEvents.RECORD_MOVED); // still okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwGIFkCiA3JGAZzgG8AoOOAJRwGEB5agEQH0BBZ5nZuAXjgAiAAIAzAJZRgqCABNgAGwD0tRiw5ceggDSUa9JmzoAJdgDkA4j35Cxk6XMUqD6k+avMde1YdZYGAGrWAiISUjLyyj7q-kGeulTRbLSxwbZhDpHOask4qfHkAL7k5KLIiADGMOIQiHCyEADKEKjAMAAW4ogA5gAUwASIMABccAAGACSk2PiERIVjAJRkcMXkDc2tHV19ofYRTkmsbpZaiwDccEpKcBAA1gCGAJ7rTS1tnT29M4PEAHRHfIXK43IjVBQKW6PJ5AA)

---

Pre TS4.1 answer:

TypeScript doesn't make it easy to widen enum value types to the string or numeric literals from which they derive.  (There is a [complication that prevents using intersections to help with this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21998)) You can get fairly close to what you want using [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types):

```
type Extractable<T, U> = T extends U ? any : never
type NotString<T> = string extends T ? never : any
function promoteStringToFMEvents<K 
  extends string & NotString<K> & Extractable<FMEvents, K>>(
  k: K
): Extract<FMEvents, K> {
  return k;
}

const fmAdded = promoteStringToFMEvents("@firemodel/RECORD_ADDED"); // FMEvents.RECORD_ADDED
const fmOops = promoteStringToFMEvents("@firemodel/RECORD_ADDLED"); // error
```

In the above code, `Extractable<T, U>` returns `any` if `T` or any of its constituents is assignable to `U`, and `never` otherwise.  And `NotString<T>` returns `any` is `T` isn't `string` or wider, and `never` otherwise.  By constraining `K` in `promoteStringToFMEvents()` to `string & NotString<K> & Extractable<FMEvents, K>`, we are saying that the type parameter `K` must be some string literal (or union of string literals) that some element (or union of elements) of `FMEvents` can be assigned to.

So the function `promoteStringToFMEvents()` will accept the string literals (or unions of string literals) you expect.  The function also just returns the associated element of `FMEvents` by assigning the input value to `Extract<FMEvents, K>`, which pulls out just those pieces of `FMEvents` which match `K`.

So you can write your `doSomething()` method such that it is generic in the type of `K` above, and in the implementation of the method you can (if you need to) promote the string to an enum by assigning it to a variable of type `Extract<FMEvents, K>`.

EDIT with explicit implementation of `doSomething()`:

```
class Blomp {
  public doSomething<K
    extends string & NotString<K> & Extractable<FMEvents, K>>(k: K) {
    // k is of some subtype of "@firemodel/RECORD_ADDED" | 
    // "@firemodel/RECORD_CHANGED" | "@firemodel/RECORD_MOVED" |
    // "@firemodel/RECORD_REMOVED"

    // if you need to interpret k as a subtype of FMEvents, you can:
    const kAsFMEvent: Extract<FMEvents, K> = k;

    // or even wider as just FMEvents
    const fmEvent: FMEvents = kAsFMEvent;

    // do what you want here
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Wow that is quite complicated. I figured I was missing a keyword not a few paragraphs. Thanks very much. Out grabbing a taco but will try as soon as I’m back.

Comment: my head's still spinning a bit ... how do I get type `K` associated with my doSomething method? I don't think at this point I need to promote so much as _demote_. If that makes sense.

Comment: I've just edited with `doSomething()` accepting a type `K` which is constrained to the string literal types associated with `FMEvents`.

Comment: It all works. Many thanks. My one remaining question ... is there a way of encapsulating this logic in one place so that functions that have this type have a more shorthand way of expressing it? I tried `export type IFMEvent<K> = K extends string & NotString<K> & Extractable<FMEvents, K>;` but it complained that "Exported type alias 'IFMEvent' has or is using private name ''."

Comment: You should be able to do that, but the "using private name" message is weird; you should make sure to export all referenced names (such as `NotString` and `Extractable` and see if it gets better.

Comment: There is now a much simpler alternative; check the other answer

Answer (score 5):

The list of values of an enum can be infered as a type with some help of the [template literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) operator:

```js
export enum FMEvents {
  RECORD_ADDED = "@firemodel/RECORD_ADDED",
  RECORD_CHANGED = "@firemodel/RECORD_CHANGED",
  RECORD_MOVED = "@firemodel/RECORD_MOVED",
  RECORD_REMOVED = "@firemodel/RECORD_REMOVED",
}

type FMEventsValue = `${FMEvents}`
// => type FMEventsValue = "@firemodel/RECORD_ADDED" | "@firemodel/RECORD_CHANGED" | ...

const event: FMEventsValue = "@firemodel/RECORD_ADDED"
// => ✅ OK

const event: FMEventsValue = "NoT_iN_ThE_eNuM"
// =>  KO
```

Reference article: [Get the values of an enum dynamically](https://dev.to/prod/mastering-enums-in-typescript-1c1j#enum-get-values)
*(disclaimer: author here)*