# Getting a union type with all string enum values

Tags: typescript

I have an example enum that looks like:

```
enum MyEnum {
    foo = "Lorem",
    bar = "Ipsem",
}
```

How can I get a union type that looks like `Lorem | Ipsem` from that enum?

I would like to be able to safely run functions based on string in runtime, like:

```
type myType = "Lorem" | "Ipsum";
const doStuff = (s: myType) => {
    return "foo";
};

doStuff("Lorem");
```

Except derived from the enum values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting a type for the values of a string enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884025/getting-a-type-for-the-values-of-a-string-enum)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any way to get at the string literal type underlying an enum literal type.  Your best option may be to use a namespace instead of an enum:

```
namespace MyEnum {
  export const foo = "Lorem";
  export const bar = "Ipsem";
}
type MyEnum = (typeof MyEnum)[keyof typeof MyEnum];
```

For additional background, see [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17690).

Answer (score 0):

The list of values of an enum can be infered as a type with some help of the [template literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) operator:

```js
enum MyEnum {
    foo = "Lorem",
    bar = "Ipsem",
}

type MyEnumValue = `${MyEnum}`
// => type MyEnumValue = "Lorem" | "Ipsem"

const values: MyEnumValue[] = Object.values(MyEnum)
// => ["Lorem", "Ipsem"]
```

Reference article: [Get the values of an enum dynamically](https://dev.to/prod/mastering-enums-in-typescript-1c1j#enum-get-values)
*(disclaimer: author here)*