# Calculate union of strings from enum keys

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to calculate a union of string keys for a given enum?

For example, given this:

```js
enum Fruits {
    Apple = 2,
    Orange = 3,
}
```

I'd like to generate a FruitKey type with this value:

```js
type FruitKey = 'Apple'|'Orange'; // generate this
```

Here's what I tried. I thought `Extract` and index types would help, but they don't work because keyof doesn't work on enums.

```js
type Keys = keyof Fruits; // Nope. Doesn't work, actually these are object props, not record keys.
type AllValues = Fruits[Keys]; // If the above had worked, these would be: `'Apple'|'Orange'|2|3`
type StrVals = Extract<Values, string>; // just the enum keys. Theoretically. `'Apple'|'Orange'`
```

[playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTmAlgFwM5QN4Cgq6gQQAdCAbYKAXigCYAaHPAeTgEMQBzcqgZnoF8sWZAE9C5ANLBh6KgGspAewBmsBClQBuKAHptUACJxgLCIg4A6AwuCoQAcmRQA7grizaUFgGNkYFiRJhKGQACxtyFiMoBQAjACtgHyhCOAVCVCFRcgA1fzAbSlUkNABtSWkAXS1dYLCoEhRgVhIoIxTwkGQWZEQFEGiVUMR0FzASABMoGOAALigAAzsiUmA7AB87ZjZOdeo17nnMsSgAYUKAUQAPZFYfAB5cknzUD1Qbs3YAPmq9OLA32rkUCQKDyaSWAAqYVcwB6Xn8gUsi2WZHWm1YHFWhyAA)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a union type with all string enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845773/getting-a-union-type-with-all-string-enum-values)

Comment: The possible dupe is about enum values, which is not (I think) possible. This question is about enum keys, which is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close with `keyof Fruit`. You don't want the keys of a member of the `Fruit` enum (which is what the `Fruit` type represents). You want the keys of the object containing the enum members:

```
enum Fruits {
    Apple = 2,
    Orange = 3,
}

type Keys = keyof typeof Fruits;
```

Comment: Get out of town! I don't even need the `Extract`. Thank you!