# Typescript: Use `enum` values as `type`

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript3.0

I would like to use following `enum`'s values:

```js
export enum GenFormats {
    SHORT_LOWER = 'm/f', SHORT_UPPER = 'M/F', FULL = 'Male/Female'
};
```

as type given below:

```
export interface IGenderOptions {
    format: 'm/f' | 'M/F' | 'Male/Female'
};
```

by using Type extraction/definition something like:

```
{{some type cast/logic}}<GenFormats>    // Outputs: 'm/f' | 'M/F' | 'Male/Female'
```

## Updated Question:

Here is my code:

```
export enum EGenderFormats {
    SHORT_LOWER = 'm/f', SHORT_UPPER = 'M/F', FULL = 'Male/Female'
};

export interface IGenderFormats {
    SHORT_LOWER: 'm/f'; SHORT_UPPER: 'M/F'; FULL: 'Male/Female';
};

export interface IGenderOptions {
    format: IGenderFormats[keyof IGenderFormats]
};

const DEFAULTS: IGenderOptions = {
    format: EGenderFormats.FULL
};
```

My question is, how can I use single entity either `enum EGenderFormats` or `interface IGenderFormats` instead of both?

I am using Typescript 3.2.2

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post your code on stackblitz and elaborate your problem?

Comment: @dileepkumar jami, I have provided maximum description I could.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting a type for the values of a string enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884025/getting-a-type-for-the-values-of-a-string-enum)

Comment: @jcalz , I updated my question, please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Enum as a type:

```
export enum EGenderFormats {
  SHORT_LOWER = "m/f",
  SHORT_UPPER = "M/F",
  FULL = "Male/Female"
}

type SGenderOptions = "m/f" | "M/F" | "Male/Female"

export interface IGenderOptions {
  format: EGenderFormats | SGenderOptions;
}

const DEFAULTS: IGenderOptions = {
  format: EGenderFormats.FULL
};

const OTHER_DEFAULTS: IGenderOptions = {
  format: "M/F"
};
```

Comment: Doing this does not accept `const DEFAULTS: IGenderOptions = { format: 'Male/Female' };`

Comment: I think that if you enforce the format options using an enum, there's to reason to allow string input. Either way you can't have both worlds unless you use a union type. I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: Cannot we create `type` dynamically using `enum` or `interface` using some Advanced type features? I am using latest Typescript.

Comment: I fail to understand why you insist having it both ways, nor can I find a TypeScript way to declare such a type.

Comment: @Vikram yes, you can do: type YourType = `${ EGenderFormats }`;

Answer (score 2):

I think with the latest TypeScript you can just assign it.
This is how I set up my easy-peasy store in an app for pages using enum

```
import { Action, action, createStore } from "easy-peasy";
import { createTypedHooks } from "easy-peasy";

interface IStoreModel {
  page: Pages;
  setPage: Action<IStoreModel, Pages>;
}

enum Pages {
  Home = "home",
  Admin = "admin",
}

const typedHooks = createTypedHooks<IStoreModel>();

const store = createStore<IStoreModel>({
  page: Pages.Admin,
  setPage: action((state, payload) => {
    state.page = payload;
  }),
});

export const useStoreActions = typedHooks.useStoreActions;
export const useStoreDispatch = typedHooks.useStoreDispatch;
export const useStoreState = typedHooks.useStoreState;
```

Also, look here for the answer, you will definitely find it :)
https://blog.logrocket.com/typescript-string-enums-guide

typeof ;)

Answer (score 2):

this is an old question but none of the answers really answering it,
maybe you looking for:

```
keyof typeof EGenderFormats
```