# How to type enum values with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, enums

Given a simple `enum`:

```
export enum IconNames {
  DEFAULT = 'DEFAULT',
  MOVE = 'MOVE',
  RESIZE = 'RESIZE',
  ADD = 'ADD',
  CANCEL = 'CANCEL',
  CLOSE = 'CLOSE',
}
```

I would like to type the `name` argument in the given function `isTransform` so I would call it only with `IconNames` value:

```
/* Tried `string` which doesn't work 
as `name` supposed to be enum's value */

const isTransform = (name: any) => [IconNames.MOVE, IconNames.RESIZE, IconNames.ADD].includes(name);
```

Do I have to build an interface for it? How do I use it?

- [How to build a type from enum values in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142177/how-to-build-a-type-from-enum-values-in-typescript)

Comment: I think that this answers your question pretty nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68747948/346005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
function isTransform(name: string): boolean {
  const transformValues: string[] = [IconNames.MOVE, IconNames.RESIZE, IconNames.ADD]
  return transformValues.indexOf(name) > -1
}
```

This works as well:

```
function isTransform(name: IconNames): boolean {
  const transformValues = [IconNames.MOVE, IconNames.RESIZE, IconNames.ADD]
  return transformValues.indexOf(name) > -1
}
```

The question here is would you be calling `isTransform` only with `IconNames` values or with a `string`?

Comment: I updated the question, sorry, yes I want to call it with IconNames values

Comment: see the second example in my answer, doesn't it answer this usecase?